# How to get URL Query String values

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring Framework and I want to get query string values in Controller

```
api/asset?param1=value&param2=value
```

some parameters can be empty like this

```
api/asset?param1=value&param2
```

Here is code for controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/assets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getAssetList(
        @RequestParam("limit") int limit,
        @RequestParam("offset") int offset
        ) {

}
```

I got it working when both parameters are given, but I cannot get values when one parameter is empty

Comment: If the parameter is empty, it is a bad formed query string.

Answer (score 3):

Parameters are mandatory by default but you can set them as optional.

Take a look at spring documentation here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

> Parameters using this annotation are required by default, but you can
>   specify that a parameter is optional by setting @RequestParam's
>   required attribute to false (e.g., @RequestParam(value="id",
>   required=false)).